# How to Insert and retrieve a decimal value in hive table

Tags: java, sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to insert and retrieve a decimal value in hive table. 
Here is my snippet which always returns NULL:

```
CREATE TABLE complex_types (c1 decimal);

INSERT INTO TABLE complex_types SELECT cast('100' as decimal);

SELECT * FROM complex_types;
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for here?

Comment: I want a way to properly insert a decimal value in hive table, How can I do that?

Comment: Hive is not SQL Server, you cannot have a `SELECT value` without a FROM. And it is not Oracle, you have no equivalent to "DUAL" dummy table with 1 dummy record.

Comment: And you should define explicitly the scale/precision of your DECIMAL e.g. `DECIMAL(22,7)` for 15+7 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read and write values in such a table using either the LazySimpleSerDe or the LazyBinarySerDe.

For example:

`alter table decimal_1 set serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe';`
or

```
alter table decimal_1 set serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyBinarySerDe';
```

source information is [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-string)